# How can I use a StateFlow variable in a HiltViewModel based on Room parameterised using @AssistedInject?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I have a Room Database, Using Compose and have a working app framework.

Part of the app has a list of objects and a navigation stack that allows list-detail navigation.

I am using a StateFlow approach in all the view models to extract the relevant data to display, in the list view, I built it like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: myRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val uiState: StateFlow<ListUiState> = myRepository
        .items.map<List<ListEntity>, ListUiState>(::Success)
        .catch { emit(Error(it)) }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), ListUiState.Loading)
```

This works beautifully.

When navigating to the detail view, I originally tried to set up param passing via SavedStateHandle, but could not get it to work (plus it seemed somewhat "kludgy").

I then discovered the parameter passing in Hilt using @AssistedInject. So Implemented that and got the parameter passing working:

```
@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = ItemViewModel.ItemViewModelFactory::class)
class ItemViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val itemId: String,
    repository: myRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val uiState : StateFlow<ItemUiState> = myRepository
        .subItems(itemId)
        .map<List<ItemEntity>, ItemUiState>(::Success)
        .catch { emit(CaseState.Error(it)) }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), ItemUiState.Loading)
```

But when it's instantiated in the composable view in order to pass the parameter through to the constructor like this:

```
@Composable fun CaseScreen(itemId: String, navController: NavController) {

val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ItemViewModel, ItemViewModel.ItemViewModelFactory> { factory ->
    factory.create(itemId)
}
```

It seems to (understandably) make the constructor run on the Main Thread, which means I of course get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.incredible.app, PID: 24101
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.kt:439) 
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.kt:479)
at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.kt:75)
```

Yes, I am aware I can just disable that tripwire and use Room on the main thread. But I am more interested in understanding how this StateFlow setup works in a "standard" ViewModel (ie: it's not on the main thread during creation) and how to replicate that in this approach?

Yes, I thought of investigating a synchronous coroutine to a background thread, but that is just another kludge.

So I am sort of thinking I need to either:

1. Somehow trigger the creation of the ViewModel on a background thread in a way that just "works", or
2. Create the StateFlow in the view model during initiation using a "loading" state and then trigger a background process to replace the state with the room query call post initiation.

Hoping some ultra smart people can help me work out the "correct" way to do this.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

OK, I "fixed" the first issue by doing this:

```
    var cases : StateFlow<ItemUIState> = callbackFlow<List<ItemEntity>> {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        trySend(
            myRepository
                .subItems(itemId)
        )
    }
}
    .map<List<ItemEntity>, ItemUIState>(ItemUIState::Success)
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    .catch { emit(ItemUIState.Error(it)) }
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), ItemUIState.Loading)
```

Which essentially makes the query run on the background thread and have a delayed return to via the callbackFlow block.

But it seems wrong. in that same view model I have 2 ui states both calling the database and only one of them is barfing. And in another view model I did it again and it's working fine.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be misbehaving?

Comment: OK, this is really strange. I cannot figure out why, but I built another pair of view and view model in this fashion and they work fine. But I also "fixed" (hacked) the first view model to work with a really odd kludge. I'll edit the question to show the "fix", but I'm not happy with it.